# The session id is too long or contains illegal characters

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I've got a problem on a site where sometimes there is logged an warning like:

```
session_start() [<a href='0function.session-start0'>function.session-start0</a>]: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'
```

I went further and dumped the `$_SERVER` variable:

`[HTTP_COOKIE] => name2=; name1=; my_session=; __gads=; __utma=; __utmc=; __utmz=`

The requests are coming all over the world, they are not many, 1-2 per day which comes in this format ( I mean all cookies seam to be empty? ).

Any clue in what conditions and why is this happening ? An how this should be handled ? `session_regenerate_id()` does nothing I still get the same warning

Answer (score 0):

According to that post https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-fast-secure-contact-form-the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters

it could be your web host the problem...